# Neo4j, Cypher: How to update a property name?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a set of nodes with a property, **myproperty = "James"** I want to update that property from (myproperty) to (name).

Is there any way to this with Cypher?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Solved by myself, heres what I did:

```
MATCH (n:term)
SET n.name = n.label
REMOVE n.label
RETURN n
```

Comment: You should be able to remove the old property right after you set the new, all in one query. If you have a satisfactory answer to your question feel free to accept your own answer to consider the question 'closed'.

Comment: thank you, I just figured it out. I'm a newbie with cypher, thanks for editing the answer though.

Answer (score 1):

```
match (a:employee {employeeId:123,location:1}) 
set a.newProperty=a.oldProperty 
remove a.oldProperty 
return a;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change your old column name by using following query

```
MATCH (n:term)
SET n.name = n.myproperty
REMOVE n.myproperty
RETURN n
```